# Openbox Button Images are misaligned

Tags: openbox

I'm trying to setup my Openbox environment but I having an issue. Everytime I installed a new theme, I always get the Windows Titles icons misaligned.

For example, this Nord-Openbox theme:

[image: nord-openbox]

And this Arc-Clone

[image: arc-clone]

But other themes that come by default are fine.

---

My specs:

```
annahri@arch-hp 
--------------- 
OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
Host: HP Pavilion Notebook 
Kernel: 5.12.14-arch1-1 
Uptime: 37 mins 
Packages: 1786 (pacman) 
Shell: bash 5.1.8 
Resolution: 1600x900 
WM: Openbox 
WM Theme: Nord-Openbox 
Theme: Zukitwo-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Crule-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: xterm 
Terminal Font: JetBrains Mono 
CPU: Intel Pentium N3700 (4) @ 2.400GHz 
GPU: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile 
Memory: 1067MiB / 3787MiB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just need to adjust the Font Size. Then the icons will adapt accordingly. If I set the Font Size too small, it will clip the Button Images.

Reference: [Sizing Custom Window Icons for Openbox](https://www.jasong-designs.com/2015/05/05/sizing-custom-window-icons-for-openbox/)